# Flash 11.2 sdk definition of base class Sprite was not found

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flashdevelop, starling-framework

I'm trying to build a simple sample project using FlashDevelop using Flash 11.2. For some reason it wont let me extend Sprite. When I try to compile it just says:

col: 31 Error: The definition of base class Sprite was not found.

All I have in my code is:

```
public class Game extends Sprite
{
}
```

Comment: Try a clean build if you have the correct `import` statements in place. If that fails, try wrapping your class in a `package` statement and check.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you have the following setup in your Flex SDK installation correctly:

\frameworks\libs\player\11.2\playerglobal.swc

and that you have a compiler constant called "swf-version=15" set in FD.

If that doesn't solve it, you have an ambiguous path to your libs. May they have spaces or special characters in them.

Answer (score 0):

Did you import the right package? flash.display.Sprite

Answer (score 0):

You put starling-framework as a tag so if you're using Starling it should be:

```
import starling.display.Sprite;
```